# ¿Como ocultar una notificación push? Onesignal

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

Tengo ese problema. Utilizo el servicio de oneSignal para generar notificaciones web push y logré que funcionara pero se queda ahí hasta que no le a la "X" y no quisiera que estuviese ahí todo el tiempo sino que desaparezca a los 20 segundos por ejemplo.

http://prntscr.com/jid75j

Tengo este codigo:

```
OneSignal.sendSelfNotification(
    /* Title (defaults if unset) */
    "Nombre",
    /* Message (defaults if unset) */
    "Mensaje",
    /* URL (defaults if unset) */
    'www.misitio.com',
    /* Icon */
    'www.misitio.com/ejemplo.png', {
        /* Additional data hash */
        notificationType: 'news-feature'
    }
);
```

Y para activarlo este:

```
<script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

    OneSignal.push(function() {

        OneSignal.init({
            appId: "af375586-a3b7-4619-bc0c-7060d5100966",
            autoRegister: true,
            notifyButton: {
                enable: true
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Has mirado la documentación? está algo oculta https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Comment: Si, busqué y busqué y no encuentro algo sobre esto

Comment: Mira esto , https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-options#section-notification-persistence  , segun entiendo con persistNotification   desaparece luego de 20s pero no puedes modificar el tiempo

Comment: Genial, si me sirvió lo tuyo!